# How do I return a literal JSON string as a JSON object

Tags: java, json, spring, jackson

I just started my first development job and the company is using the Spring framework. The person who built the current REST service retired so I'm here for help. This is how they are currently using it:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/hello", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<?> hello() {
    ModelMap map = new ModelMap();
    map.put("Hello", "World");
    return new ResponseEntity<ModelMap>(map, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

That returns `{"Hello":"World"}`

I need to add a new method that has the JSON already generated as a java String but it is only returning a String with quotes instead of a JSON object. My new method:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/test", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json")
public ResponseEntity<?> getMessage() {

    HttpHeaders responseHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
    responseHeaders.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);

    String response = "{\"message\":\"The message value.\"}";
    return new ResponseEntity<String>(response, responseHeaders, HttpStatus.OK);
 }
```

This returns `"{\"message\":\"The message value.\"}"`

It's a string with the quotes outside with all the inside quotes escaped instead of plain JSON like the first method. How can I stop this from returning a String and return a JSON object without the end quotes and escaping?

Comment: The returned object is correct! If you are consuming the resource on rest-client, you should be getting correct values, but if it is service-serivce call, then you need to map into object to get the actual string representation

Comment: your problem is solved?

Comment: No, so my example above is a simplified version of the real problem. We are using Spring with Jackson. It works great for converting POJOs however I have an object that generates the JSON itself. When I return it, I believe Spring/Jackson is passing it through the converter and turning it into a string instead of allowing me to pass it back as a native JSON object. Hopefully you can make sense of what I'm asking because I'm really new to Spring/Jackson.